# How to filter records of ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have following Django models:

```
class TopicLabel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    topics = models.ManyToManyField(Topic, through='TopicLabelConnection')

class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    visible = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('topic')
        verbose_name_plural = _('topics')

class TopicLabelConnection(models.Model):
    topicId = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='connection_topic')
    labelId = models.ForeignKey(TopicLabel, related_name='connection_label')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.labelId.name + ' / ' + self.topicId.title
```

I want to create a method of `TopicLabel`, which will return to me all topics in the `TopicLabel.topic` collection, which have `Topic.visible = True`.

I want to program a Django equivalent of the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPINIONS_TOPICLABELCONNECTION, OPINIONS_TOPIC
WHERE (OPINIONS_TOPICLABELCONNECTION.topicId_id = OPINIONS_TOPIC.id) AND
    (OPINIONS_TOPICLABELCONNECTION.labelId_id = X) AND 
    (OPINIONS_TOPIC.visible = 1)
```

where `X` is the primary key of the topic label.

I tried following method definitions and they all failed:

1)

```
class TopicLabel(models.Model):
    [...]
    def getVisibleTopics():
        return topics.filter(connection_topic__visible=True)
```

2)

```
class TopicLabel(models.Model):
    [...]
    def getVisibleTopics():
        return topics.filter(visible=True)
```

3)

```
class TopicLabel(models.Model):
    [...]
    def getVisibleTopics():
        return Topic.objects.filter(connection_label__visible=True).filter(connection_label__id=self.id)
```

4)

```
class TopicLabel(models.Model):
    [...]
    def getVisibleTopics():
        return Topic.objects.filter(connection_label__visible=True).filter(connection_label__id=self.id)
```

5)

```
class TopicLabel(models.Model):
    [...]
    def getVisibleTopics():
        return topics.filter(connection_topicId__visible=True)
```

What is the correct code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to have `self` as the first parameter on a method. Then filter the topics. try this:

```
class TopicLabel(models.Model):
    [...]
    def getVisibleTopics(self):
        return self.topics.filter(visible=True)
```

Also, is there a reason you are creating a custom through table? It doesn't look like you are adding any extra data to it.